# TextBox handle key events and don't pass them on

Tags: c#, keyboard, uwp, keyboard-events

I have a uwp app with some global keypress handling. I do it by subscribing to two different sets of events:

```
CoreWindow.CharacterReceived (for text keypresses), and
MainPage.KeyDown (for escape, arrow keys, enter, etc.)
```

But my app also has some TextBoxes. When one of those has focus, I want to disable the above in almost all cases. (arrow keys and tab are sometimes exceptions).

I could certainly do that by overriding OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus in my TextBox wrapper objects and keeping track of whether or not a TextBox currently has focus.

Is there a better way?

EDIT: I've found FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(). This is an improvement, but still does not feel ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()` and check whether the returned element is of type `TextBox`. So you should add something like this to your `CoreWindow.CharacterReceived` and `MainPage.KeyDown` event handlers:

```
EventHandler(parameters)
{
    if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() is TextBox)
    {
        return;
    }

    // event handling
}
```